# 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' => Target of URI doesn't exist ERROR

Tags: firebase, flutter-dependencies

I have Firebase setup working, logged in, CLI is setup and working. The only thing that is giving me an error is: 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' Target of URI doesn't exist error (red squiggly line).

The dependency seems to be correct. I have tried every possible solution I could find on SO, Google, etc. Tried every chatGPT recommendation. Just cannot get the dependency to work.

[pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPB4j.jpg)

Here is my main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gogoapp/pages/login_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart'; 
import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here are a few things I tried:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter channel (on stable)
everything is latest version
restart IDE and restart Windows
Environment variables (Path) to Flutter and Dart setup for user (not system). I am the only one using my laptop)

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `flutter pub add firebase_core` in terminal in project root directory.